# Issues with Decomposing Trend, Seasonal, and Residual Time Series Elements

Tags: dataframe, time-series

i am quite a newbie to Time Series Analysis and this might be a stupid question.

I am trying to generate the trend, seasonal, and residual time series elements, however, my timestamps index are actually strings (lets say 'window1', 'window2', 'window3'). Now, when i try to apply `seasonal_decompose(data, model='multiplicative')`, it returns an error as, Index' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq' and which is pretty understandable.

However, how to go around this issue by keeping strings as time series index?

Answer (score 0):

Basically here you need to specify `freq` parameter.

Suppose you have following dataset

```
s = pd.Series([102,200,322,420], index=['window1', 'window2', 'window3','window4'])
s
>>>window1    102
   window2    200
   window3    322
   window4    420
   dtype: int64
```

Now specify `freq` parameter,in this case I used freq=1

```
plt.style.use('default')
plt.figure(figsize = (16,8))
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(s.values,freq=1).plot()
result = sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller(s,maxlag=1)
plt.show()
```

I am not allowed to post image ,but I hope this code will solve your problem.Also here `maxlag` by default give an error for my dataset ,therefore I used `maxlag=1`.If you are not sure about its values ,do use default value for `maxlag`.